# Image slider not working after modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I found an image slider on here and attempted to modify my existing slider I had to be more like the one I found. After tinkering with it, I am unable to get anything with it even working.

I created this to show what I am trying to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/xeud0rw6/

I'm basing it around this...http://gualini.adostudio.it/realizations_2.html#

I have added in my id's of

```
#thumb
```

and

```
#big
```

in attempts to modify this to make it work, but I think I am missing something. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you loading Jquery & bxSlider?. It has been done with bxSlider. Here you can find some examples with code: http://bxslider.com/examples

Comment: I just downloaded the bxSlider and added it to my hosts server and linked it to my page and still nothing.

Comment: the code what you have posted looks pretty awful, but the image slider used in it `bxslider`. refer this example which gives you the same image slider which your searching for http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console....Uncaught ReferenceError: $j is not defined....      for this line of code................var realSlider= $j("#big ul").bxSlider({

Comment: @dreamweiver I'm wanting the bottom thumbs to do a carousel.

Comment: Before that line goes: var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: It still gives me that error, but now gives me another one... Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function.....for this....$(".textContent").each(function() {

Comment: Ok, lets do something , delete  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();  and just replace this: .var realSlider= $j("#big ul").bxSlider({ with this:  var realSlider= $("#big ul").bxSlider({                 and try again

Comment: This actually gave me four errors now. The same two as before. This is part of the error from the last error I posted. Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(anonymous function) @ my-script.js:220m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask us to make your buggy code work, this question will not help anyone but yourself. I suggest you approach the authors of your plugin or at least specify the plugins you are speaking of.

Comment: this had to be a suggestion buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var realSlider= jQuery("#big ul").bxSlider({
            speed:1000,
            pager:false,
            nextText:'',
            prevText:'',
            infiniteLoop:false,
            hideControlOnEnd:true,
            onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
                changeRealThumb(realThumbSlider,newIndex);

            }

        });

        var realThumbSlider=jQuery("#big ul").bxSlider({
          minSlides: 4,
          maxSlides: 4,
          slideWidth: 156,
          slideMargin: 12,
          moveSlides: 1,
          pager:false,
          speed:1000,
          infiniteLoop:false,
          hideControlOnEnd:true,
          nextText:'<span></span>',
            prevText:'<span></span>',
            onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
                /*jQuery("#thumb ul .active").removeClass("active");
                $slideElement.addClass("active"); */

            }
        });

        linkRealSliders(realSlider,realThumbSlider);

        if(jQuery("#thumb li").length<5){
            jQuery("#thumb .bx-next").hide();
        }




// sincronizza sliders realizzazioni
function linkRealSliders(bigS,thumbS){

    jQuery("#thumb ul").on("click","a",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var newIndex=jQuery(this).parent().attr("slideIndex");
        bigS.goToSlide(newIndex);
    });



}

//slider!=$thumbSlider. slider is the realslider
function changeRealThumb(slider,newIndex){

    var $thumbS=jQuery("#thumb");
    $thumbS.find('.active').removeClass("active");
    $thumbS.find('li[slideIndex="'+newIndex+'"]').addClass("active");

    if(slider.getSlideCount()-newIndex>=4)slider.goToSlide(newIndex);
    else slider.goToSlide(slider.getSlideCount()-4);

}
});
```

Comment: This actually made it have more errors. My site I am trying to get this to work on is buyfarbest.com . If you go to products and click on any of them, this will come up.

Comment: You have to add bxslider library !

Comment: I did add it...  <script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script> . I saved the library in the server.

Comment: Something like <script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: it doesn't appear if I edit  html code in https://buyfarbest.com/products.php for example. You only load jquery.min.js and my-script.js

Comment: It's on the page next page if you click on one of those products.

Comment: ok, but on next page the path is wrong -> https://buyfarbest.com/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js" . This link doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, that's right but in https://buyfarbest.com/viewProduct.php?view_product=11 you have   buyfarbest.com/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js

Comment: I must have forgotten to delete it. I deleted it and just checked the console and all of the errors went away? It isn't doing anything though?

Comment: You don't have to delete it . You just have to modify the path to the script from  buyfarbest.com/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js to  buyfarbest.com/jquery.bxslider.min.js

Comment: It is like that right now. What I did was put in the paths you commented earlier with js/jquery.bxslider.min.js and the css one. When I saw they weren't helping I commented them out. The comments must not have worked, so I just went in and deleted the two. The one I have in their now is the correct one, but it is not doing anything to the images.

Comment: You are loading bxslider.min.js AFTER  my-script.js . The order have to be: jquery.min.js , bxslider.min.js and my-script.js

Comment: I changed the order and still nothing.

Comment: Ok that's because the script points to '#big ul' and it have to be updated to '#bxslider-horizontal'. just change this in your my-script.js

Comment: ok that did something, but just makes the page load and load. It seems like it is killing the page.

Comment: Until here the best thing i can recommend you is to study carefully in http://bxslider.com/  the way this library works

Comment: I appreciate all of your help.